# How parse images inside a web page with PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm sure maybe is a duplicate but i have a problem with "parsing web page with PHP".
I try to extrapolate `src`,`alt` and `title` of each element `<img>` inside a web page but i have this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on array in /web/example.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
```

To do this i creates this small code:

```
include('../simple_html_dom.php');
$doc = file_get_html('https://www.example.com');

foreach($doc-> find('div.content')-> getElementsByTagName('img') as $item){
    $src =  $item->getAttribute('src');
    $title= $item->getAttribute('title');
    $alt= $item->getAttribute('alt');

    echo "\n";
    echo $src;
    echo $title;
    echo $alt;
}
```

I hope you can help me.... thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find`](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm#section_find) returns an array of elements, so you need to iterate over each of those as well:

```
foreach($doc->find('div.content') as $div) {
    foreach ($div->getElementsByTagName('img') as $item){
        $src =  $item->getAttribute('src');
        $title= $item->getAttribute('title');
        $alt= $item->getAttribute('alt');

        echo "\n";
        echo $src;
        echo $title;
        echo $alt;
    }
}
```